# Right parenthesis on keyboard is not working, zero below works fine

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a Saitek Cyborg v7 running on Windows 7, and I am unable to type a right parenthesis (HEX 29).

- Drivers are up to date.
- Keyboard works fine (pressing <kbd>0</kbd> gives `0`, but pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> gives nothing)
- Remapping is pointless since no keyboard button gives me this right parenthesis

I suspect it is a software issue of some sort but have no clue where to start looking at.

The right parenthesis you see in this message are Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V since I can't type it.

Comment: Same result for using either shift key?

Comment: I have this same issue with a Razer Lycosa keyboard.

Comment: I'm just seeing this issue on a Windows 7 system. The 0 key works fine. Both Shift keys work fine as modifiers for other keys. However, shift-0 does nothing.

Comment: It's only happening in the native Windows dialogs in various applications. It's not affecting keyboard handling on a VirtualBox image running Ubuntu, in which I can type the parenthesis. This is something at the higher level in the Windows event queue.

Comment: I did Ctrl-Alt-Delete, then dismissed the full-screen dialog which comes up, by clicking Cancel. The problem went away!

Answer (score 1):

Have you run a virus scan? I've seen viruses attack keyboard functions (at least how they appear on screen). I use [MSE](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/), but it might be worth a try nonetheless.